# @HasMany Error - Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

## Issue

Following https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#one-to-many I have my Models set up correctly. However, I am getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "topics")`

### Versions

package.json

```
"@nestjs/axios": "^0.1.0",
"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/sequelize": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.2",
"@nrwl/angular": "^14.7.5",
"@types/snowflake-sdk": "^1.6.8",
"angular-auth-oidc-client": "^14.1.4",
"express-session": "^1.17.3",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-okta-oauth20": "^1.1.0",
"passport-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"sequelize": "^6.24.0",
"sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.3"
```

### Actual behavior

Here is my set up:

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'snowflake',
      host: 'localhost',
      dialectOptions: {
        // put your snowflake account here,
        port: '3333',
        account: 'blah',
        application: 'SNOWFLAKE',
    
        // below option should be optional
        role: 'blah',
        warehouse: 'blah',
        schema: 'blah'
      },
      // same as other dialect
      username: 'blah',
      password: 'blah',
      database: 'blah',
      define : {
        freezeTableName: true
      },
      models: ([UserTopic, User, Topic]),
      quoteIdentifiers: false
    }), DatabaseModule],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**database.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User)
        @InjectModel(Topic)
        @InjectModel(UserTopic)
        private sequelize: Sequelize,
    ) { }
          
    getUser(email: string) {
        return User.findOne({where: { email: email }, include: ["topics"]}); 
    }      
    
}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Model, Table, HasMany } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { UserTopic } from "./userTopic.entity";

@Table
export class User extends Model {
    @Column({primaryKey: true})
    id: string;

    @Column
    email: string;

    @Column
    firstName: string;

    @Column
    lastName: string;

    @Column
    login_timestamp: Date;

    @HasMany(() => UserTopic, { foreignKey: 'userId'})
    topics: UserTopic[];
}
```

**topic.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Model, Table, HasMany } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table
export class Topic extends Model {
    @Column({primaryKey: true})
    id: string;

    @Column
    name: string;

    @Column
    description: string;

    @Column
    sequence: number;
}
```

**userTopic.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Model, Table, ForeignKey, BelongsTo } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { Topic } from "./topic.entity";
import { User } from "./user.entity";

@Table
export class UserTopic extends Model {
    @Column({primaryKey: true})
    id: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    userId: string;

    @BelongsTo(() => User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
    user: User

    @ForeignKey(() => Topic)
    @Column
    topicId: string;

    @BelongsTo(() => Topic, { foreignKey: 'topicId' })
    topic: Topic

    @Column
    sequence: number;
}
```

Results:
[image]

### Expected behavior

I have a user table, topic table (with seeded default information), and a userTopic table that relates the user to the topics. A user will have many userTopics once saved.

The `Executing` query is correct and if ran in the DB no issues. What am I missing decorator/attribute wise that is causing it to fail on this `@HasMany` association?

Comment: Please turn screenshots into formatted code blocks

Comment: Did the requested changes! TY!

Answer (score 0):

To have users along with topics you need to use both models `UserTopic` and `Topic` and you used only `Topic`. You don't have a direct association between `User` and `Topic` and only have it through `UserTopic`:

```js
return User.findOne({
  where: { email },
  include: [{
    model: UserTopic,
    include: [{ model: Topic }]
  }]
})
```

Comment: Made these changes and sadly...still the same error as seen above "[Nest] 29740  - 10/10/2022, 1:44:55 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'topics')"

Comment: Please add `Topic` model defintion

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little lost. What do you mean? I need something else along with the changes you recommended?

Comment: I can't decide what to advice because I don't see the third model `Topic` (its definition)

Comment: UNDERSTOOD! I added that in as well. Sorry, long day trying to figure this out!

Comment: Can you also modify `getUser` in the post to the actual one?

Comment: This is my actual call.

Comment: Can you change it the way I showed in my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I posted above that I tried what you mentioned and it did not work. I don't want to update my issue above if it didn't work :(

Comment: Ok, but did you get other error when you tried my solution?